# Обработка огромного dataframe через pandas

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть dataframe которые весят по 25 ГБ каждый. Это выгрузка за 1 день. Pandas очень сильно тормозит когда я их загружаю. Но мне не нужен весь dataframe мне нужны из него некоторые строки. Как можно не читаю dataframe полностью отсеять его колонкам? Например, мне нужно прочитать 5 dataframe и из каждого из них достать только нужные столбцы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что бы получилось вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сложность в том что pandas делает это очень медленно, а мне нужно достать информацию из 150 ГБ

Comment: откуда читаются данные в DataFrame?

Comment: Все данные на компьютере. Читаю через  pd.read_csv

Comment: уточните в вопросе что именно вы хотите отсеять строки или столбцы?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то загрузка 25ГБ это никак не быстрый процесс.

Общего рецепта проблемы скорее всего нет. Но если бы такая проблема встала передо мной, я бы попробовал файл читать как текстовый и "на лету" вырезал бы только ту часть информации, которая в дальнейшем пригодится. Не знаю, окажется-ли это быстрее, но Pandas тратит много времени на "угадывание" типа читаемых данных, их трансформацию и пр. Вы можете придумать более простую и удобную структуру и писать в нее. Правда и прелести "Pandas" тогда вам не будут доступны.

Кроме того, вопрос про 150ГБ и "Все данные на компьютере" Это действительно так?

Comment: Кроме того, вопрос про 150ГБ и "Все данные на компьютере" Это действительно так?

Да пока это так. Сейчас ищем систему хранения данных. Будем переходить в облако